# PHP function substr() error

Tags: php, substr

When I use `substr()` I get a strange character at the end

```
$articleText = substr($articleText,0,500);
```

I have an output of 500 chars and � <--

How can I fix this?  Is it an encoding problem?  My language is Greek.

Comment: Have seen the same thing in (UK) English.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[`substr`](http://php.net/substr) is counting using bytes, and not characters.

greek probably means you are using some multi-byte encoding, like UTF-8 -- and counting per bytes is not quite good for those.

Maybe using [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) could help, here : the [`mb_*`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) functions have been created specifically for multi-byte encodings.

Comment: Learning more and more every single day... Thank you stackoverflow !

Comment: Thank you very much. But as for me the main thing is to add `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` before using `mb_*` functions. Without adding it I still see squares.

Comment: @Kremchik You won't see squares, if you use `mb_substr($short, 0, 75, 'utf-8')`. Then you don't need to use `mb_internal_encoding` before `mb_substr`.

Answer (score 20):

Use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) instead, it is able to deal with multiple encodings, not only single-byte strings as [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
$articleText = mb_substr($articleText,0,500,'UTF-8');
```

Comment: "UTF-8" part was important for me - don't forget it peeps!

Comment: "UTF-8" as optional parameter worked for me. Keep in mind that you might also want to use mb_strlen() if you are using the string length to determine if it must be cut.

Comment: An alternative is to use `mb_internal_encoding('utf-8')` before any `mb_*` command.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like you're slicing a unicode character in half there. Use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/mb_substr) instead for unicode-safe string slicing.

Comment: ...with calling `mb_internal_encoding('utf-8')` before or with using `'utf-8'` as fourth parameters of `mb_substr`. Doc says, that it is optional and when it is omitted, the internal character encoding value will be used, but the think is (explained somewhere else in PHP doc), that PHP's "internal encoding" in nearly always "something else" than your page encoding. So for slicing UTF8 string, this fourth parameter or calling `mb_internal_encoding('utf-8')` becomes required.

Answer (score 1):

use this function, It worked for me

```
function substr_unicode($str, $s, $l = null) {
    return join("", array_slice(
        preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY), $s, $l));
}
```

Credits: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php#107698

Answer (score 0):

ms_substr()  also works excellently for removing strange trailing line breaks as well, which I was having trouble with after parsing html code.  The problem was NOT handled by:

```
 trim()
```

or:

```
 var_dump(preg_match('/^\n|\n$/', $variable));
```

or:

```
str_replace (array('\r\n', '\n', '\r'), ' ', $text)
```

Don't catch.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution for UTF-8 encoded strings - this will convert UTF-8 to characters before cutting the sub-string.

```
$articleText = substr(utf8_decode($articleText),0,500);
```

To get the articleText string back to UTF-8, an extra operation will be needed:

```
$articleText = utf8_encode( substr(utf8_decode($articleText),0,500) );
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cut unicode character.So i preferred instead of `substr()` try `mb_substr()` in php.

**substr()**

```
substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

**mb_substr()**

```
mb_substr ( string $str , int $start [, int $length [, string $encoding ]] )
```

For more information for substr() - [Credits => Check Here](http://www.queryhome.com/63397/substr-vs-strstr-in-php)