# Using PHP's substr() with special characters at the end results in question marks

Tags: php, substr

When I use the substr() function in PHP, I get an question mark (a square with a question mark - depending on the browser) at the end of the string when this last character was a special one, like ë or ö, etc...

```
$introtext = html_entity_decode($item->description, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");
$introtext = substr($introtext, 0, 200);
```

How can I escape this?

Comment: not a Joomla question, pure php can solve this (Sruit A.Suk's answer works best)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP function substr() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973649/php-function-substr-error)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

If your string has multibyte encoding (like UTF-8) does, you should use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) to avoid problems like this:

```
$introtext=mb_substr($introtext,0,200);
```

Comment: This doesn't work with scandinavian letters like åäö, needed to add utf-8 like Sruit A.Suk suggested

Comment: Ahh this helped me greatly. Special characters were causing issues so after a lot of debugging I found that the cause was $myString[$i] which also gave the same invalid result with substr. However mb_substr has now fixed the issue completely.

Comment: @SeanMcManus Yep, you'll find that [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

Answer (score 7):

In case someone tried the previous answers, and it still didn't work:

Try to add a Unicode name in `mb_substr` like:

```
$introtext = mb_substr($introtext, 0, 200, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Accepted answer didn't worked for me, I needed to it your way to get it working with scandinavian characters. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use [mb_substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Comment: How is this different from all the previous answers?

Answer (score 5):

That is because substr does not work with multibyte characters. substr will probably cut a multibyte character "in half". You should instead use [mb_substr](http://php.net/mb_substr). Also make sure that your file is saved in UTF-8.

```
$introtext = mb_substr($introtext, 0, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above worked for me!
I just used mb_strcut and that fixed the issue!

```
$introtext = mb_strcut($stringWithOddCharacters, 0, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `mb_substr` instead of `substr` that solves problems like that, but before that check `mb_string` is enabled in your PHP configuration by:

```
php -i | grep mbstring
```

It would show you that the `mb_string` is enabled or not. If not you can install that by: (for PHP 8.0)

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-mbstring
```

Now you can use [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) like this:

> mb_substr(string $string, int $start, int $length, string $encoding): string

```
$introtext = mb_substr($introtext, 0, 200, 'UTF-8');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using **Cyrillic symbols in Bulgarian**. I had **RSS Feeds and it even broke my entire page** with different feeds.

Using [mb_substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php) helped me to solve it. Now there are no more question mark symbols `(?)` at the end of the string.

```
$your_text = mb_substr($tex_to_substring, 0, 200);
```

Cheers.